# Does "unioned" exist in the context of math?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

In mathematics, if you have the sets A and B, you can build a new set C which is the union of A and B.
I would like to say, something like

> Set C consists of the unioned sets A and B.

but the form "unioned" doesn't seem to exist. But what do I say then? *united*? Sounds so strange in that context...

Comment: The term would be considered valid (though perhaps "jargon") by many computer programmers.

Comment: It's informal mathematical language, made by verbing the noun 'union'. The more formal way of saying it would be: __"Let set C be the union of sets A and B."__

Comment: I would think mathematicians would use *joined* instead of *unioned*.

Comment: And on .arxiv.org, Google finds two instances of *"the joined sets"*, both of which are in this context, and none of *"the unioned sets"*. Lots of instances of *"the combined sets"*, but most of these are in the context of datasets. So *"the joined sets"* or *"the combined sets"* are both preferable to *"the unioned sets"*.

Comment: What's worse, mathematicians will even say "quotiented".

Comment: As with "all the numbers in the list should be added" we would write "all the sets in the list should be unioned".  I have probably never written that, but (since it would be understood) why not?  On the other hand, there does exist the verb "unionize" (= "form into  a union").  "All the sets in the list should be unionized."  I like it.

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen the term `unioned` before in an academic context, and such usage appears to be rare. Mathematical (and other scientific) papers will often use the term `Set C consists of the union of sets A and B` or a similar phrasing to describe your example.

For example, the search term ["unioned" on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22unioned%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) returns ~4000 hits. In comparison, the search term ["union of" sets](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22union%20of%22%20sets&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) returns ~2 million hits.

While it may be understandable as an obvious verb-form neologism, it is definitely not commonly used, and there is no need to coin the verb-form since a much less awkward sounding version already exists.

Answer (score 2):

In my math classes, it was always said, "Sets A and B *combine* to form set C."  The verb used was "to combine," not "to union."  I've never heard of "to union."

Answer (score 0):

It's used in a surgical context quite a lot to describe how well the borders of a skin wound have "unioned" together after a suture repair. The opposing skin borders of a previously repaired wound that has undergone a dehiscence are said to be non-unioning.

Comment: Hi GuestDoc, welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your contribution, but we really need some evidence to back up your claim. I've looked through Google Books at every mention of "unioned" (there's not many!) but there are ***no*** usages in a medical context. Can you [edit] your answer to cite (and provide a link to) a published example? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)